# Table in dataset has been cleared too when clear a different table

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

I assigned a table data in dataset to a new table. When I clear the new table(dt), table(ds.Tables[0]) in dataset has been cleared too, why? And how to avoid it to be cleared too?

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
\\some code to assign data to ds
```

below code will execute when a button is clicked, first click works well,second click caused table[0] in ds empty

```
dt.Clear()
dt = ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: dt will have different data from other ds/function. So I clear it everytime before assign data. I can reassign data to ds but is there a way to keep it as it takes some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
dt = ds.Tables[0];
```

to:

```
dt = ds.Tables[0].Copy();
```

This way, `dt` will hold a *copy of* `dt.Tables[0]`, rather than a reference to the same underlying `DataTable`